# Regex to not match expressions that contain a specific number

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want to match a regex like this

```
] prima 1 words 2 words
```

And not if it's

```
] prima 1 words 2 words 3 words
```

My trial is this one:

```
\]\s*prima\s*1([\w\s]+)\s2([\w\s][^3]+)
```

But it matches only part of the expression I don't want to match at all. My exclusion si wrong. How to do it? I need to insert it in `re.compile` so it has to be one line.

Comment: You want to match words but not when there is a word preceded by a space and 3?

Comment: Well when there is a 3, space and other words! It's not like "3hello", but rather "3 hello"

Comment: In that order, perhaps like `^\](?: (?!3\b)\d+ \w+)+$` https://regex101.com/r/kkOdxU/1 or a more broad version `^\](?: (?!3\b)\w+)+$` https://regex101.com/r/vJzDuq/1

Comment: I want to match exatcly "] prima 1 words  2 words", if I insert your expression it's gonna match also 4 words 5 words. "words" is for words, ot words literally ofc

Comment: If you want to match it exactly `^\] prima 1 \w+ 2 \w+$` https://regex101.com/r/rqklVu/1

Comment: That's it, thanks! Only "one or more words", how to put it?

Comment: If the words that follow can not also start with a digit, you could use a repeating pattern where the words after matching 1 and 2 do not start with a digit `^\] prima 1 [^\W\d]\w*(?: [^\W\d]\w*)* 2 [^\W\d]\w*(?: [^\W\d]\w*)*$` https://regex101.com/r/jpBZZa/1 Note that when using the previous pattern, you would also match `] prima 1 2 2 1` See https://regex101.com/r/3eqUhA/1

Comment: Or if there can not only words that consists only of digits `^\] prima 1 (?!\d+\b)\w+(?: (?!\d+\b)\w+)* 2 (?!\d+\b)\w+(?: (?!\d+\b)\w+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/wmCUHo/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern will match the example data, but note that `\w` by itself can also match a digit.

If you want to match 1 or more whitespace characters (which could also match newlines), you could use `\s+` instead of a space.

```
^\] prima 1 \w+ 2 \w+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rqklVu/1)

If you want to match `] prima` followed by 1 and 2 which by them selves can be followed by 1 or more words that can not start with a digit:

```
^] prima 1 [^\W\d]\w*(?: [^\W\d]\w*)* 2 [^\W\d]\w*(?: [^\W\d]\w*)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `] prima 1`  Match literally
- `[^\W\d]\w*` Match a word char does not start with a digit
- `(?: [^\W\d]\w*)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a space and a word that does not start with a digit
- `2`  Match literally
- `[^\W\d]\w*` Match a word char does not start with a digit
- `(?: [^\W\d]\w*)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a space and a word that does not start with a digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mhQArP/1)

If the following words can not consists solely of digits, you can use a negative lookahead `(?!\d+\b)` checking for digits only

```
^\] prima 1 (?!\d+\b)\w+(?: (?!\d+\b)\w+)* 2 (?!\d+\b)\w+(?: (?!\d+\b)\w+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wmCUHo/1)

Comment: Hey, this is great and it matches on regex101, but if I put it in re.compile it doesn't work. Why?!

Comment: @Anna Did you use `re.MULTILINE` like `regex = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE)` See this example https://ideone.com/FGWypM

Comment: I'm checking and this matches 6/19 occurrences: `\]\s*prima\s*1\s*(?!\d+\b)\w+(?:\s(?!\d+\b)\w+)*\s*2\s(?!\d+\b)\w+(?: (?!\d+\b)\w+)*$`

Comment: no, just this: `FIND_FASE123T_PRIMA = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*(?!\d+\b)\w+(?:\s(?!\d+\b)\w+)*\s*2\s(?!\d+\b)\w+(?: (?!\d+\b)\w+)*$")`

Comment: Maybe the boundary?

Comment: It should match 19/19 instead? Can you add the data it should match to the regex101 link?

Comment: Yes, this is an example: tante libertà]  prima 1 m  2 certe lib  ertà , 
 and I'll be putting a regex 101 link soon

Comment: @Anna Try removing the anchor `^` at the beginning of the pattern https://regex101.com/r/G7M9Xf/1

Comment: Thank you! Look at how it behaves here though: https://regex101.com/r/mhQArP/1 it takes only some

Comment: @Anna I see, you can repeat the whitespace char 0 or 1 or more times using `\s*` or `\s+` https://regex101.com/r/QfIevD/1

Comment: I'm making some trials because it still takes 9 out of 19, I have to see what it doesn't match

Comment: I think one problem is that it won't match if there is a final whitespace: https://regex101.com/r/QfIevD/2

Comment: This is great! Last help: this case https://regex101.com/r/5TTiwv/2

Comment: @Anna It depends, you could change the `\w` to match all non whitespace chars which will be a broad match as `\w` does not match `]` https://regex101.com/r/uIMe2L/1 But you could also turn it into a character class `[\w\]]` adding matching `]` only https://regex101.com/r/3ONz6P/1

Comment: the first one works better, but it takes → also and I don't want to match strings with → in it. The second one takes 7 only, the first one takes 21! But it's way better than before :)

Comment: @Anna Then I would recommend adding all the characters that you would allow to the character class.